# Sharepoint Designer - Disable task has been changed alert

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I created the workflow in sharepoint designer using Collect data from user option. The approver receives three automated mail.

1) Notification to approve - Task assigned email
2) After approval, task has been changed alert
3) Another task has been changed alert

Is there an option to suppress the last two task has been changed alert? I would like to send only the Task assigned mail to approver

Answer (score 1):

The first "You've been assigned a task" email is a feature of the Task list template and can be changed in List Settings > Advance Settings > Send e-mail when ownership is assigned.

The second two emails are "Alert me" emails. (*Not sure why you are getting two, I suspect you my have signed up with 2 different users accounts that could even have the same email address.)*

To delete the Alert Me for the currently logged on user.

Actions > Alert Me > View my existing alerts on this site

Then select your alert and Delete.

By the way - this is not a programming related question (See FAQ top right) so you may get quicker answers by posting similar questions on sites such as [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) or [SharePoint.SE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Peter O. - I rolled back edit as you're making large changes to other peoples answers (you also added 2 paragraphs Reach High's answer) that are far over and above whats normally acceptable here. Perhaps it would be better if you provide your own answer rather an heavily editing other peoples?

Comment: I added the two paragraphs because Reach High posted those paragraphs in a second answer, where that answer appeared to merely add to the first answer.  Moreover, as for the text I tried to delete from your answer (namely, that this is not the right place to ask this question) it was better that it belonged as a comment to this question rather than as part of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you created your workflow in a "Task" list that has the email alert to "Assigned To" enabled. You can disable this feature under Settings, List Settings, Advanced Settings.

Your approver likely has "Alert Me" features enabled for this list. You can delete these under Action, All Site Settings, User Alerts.

As a side note. Answer to the question this title sounds like it is asking: The "Send e-mail when ownership is assigned" feature in "Tasks" lists on SharePoint often causes problems by sending unwanted emails like the task has been changed alert this question refers to. For those of us who Own sites below the site collection level and do not have access to the top level. Here is a way to fix such problems.

Turn of the "Send e-mail when ownership is assigned" feature and design a workflow in SharePoint designer that mirrors this feature minus to portion of the functionality that is not wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue and after a research i found a solution that works well for me. I have used Sharepoint Manager 2007 http://www.codeplex.com/. Just use it and do the following as in screen dump:
http://sharepointburger.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/sp20071.png

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution:
["Task has been Changed" Email Alerts Issue](http://sharepoint.ginni.me/2009/11/task-changed-email-alerts.html)